# Powershell replace between start and end

Tags: powershell

I need to replace everything between two points.

```
$import = Get-Content C:\bookmarks.html
$newbody = Get-Content C:\newbookmarks.html
$remove = '(?<=<DT><H3 ADD_DATE=""1544626193"" LAST_MODIFIED=""154649885"">Import-IE</H3>).*?(?=</DL>)'
$import | %{$_.replace($remove,"$newbody")}
```

My problem is to get all content between start:

```
<DT><H3 ADD_DATE=""1544626193"" LAST_MODIFIED=""154649885"">Import-IE</H3>
```

and the end:

```
</DL>
```

incl multiple lines

Example html:

```
<DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1544626193" LAST_MODIFIED="1546498855">Import-IE</H3>  
<DL><p>
<DT><A HREF=https://www.golem.de/ ADD_DATE="1544626193" LAST_MODIFIED="1546498842">golem.de</A>
<DT><A HREF=https://www.heise.de/ ADD_DATE="1544626193" LAST_MODIFIED="1546498842">heise online</A>
</DL>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of changes needed to make this work:

### One big multiline string

Since you want to do a replace over multiple lines, we need to makes sure all the lines are contained in the same string, so let's start with that - we can use the `-Raw` parameter switch with `Get-Content`:

```
$import = Get-Content C:\bookmarks.html -Raw
```

### Exact pattern matching in regex

Next up we have the regex pattern itself - there's a few discrepancies between that and the sample content you've shown:

```
LAST_MODIFIED=""154649885"" # pattern has nested double-quotes and only one 5 at the end
LAST_MODIFIED="1546498855"  # input uses just one pair of double-quotes and value has two 5's at the end
```

So let's fix that, and make sure the input string we're looking for is properly escaped while we're at it:

```
$remove = "(?<=$([regex]::Escape('<DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1544626193" LAST_MODIFIED="1546498855">Import-IE</H3>'))).*?(?=</DL>)"
```

### String.Replace doesn't support regex

Then, we'll have to abandon the `String.Replace()` method that you're currently using - because it doesn't actually support regex - so we'll use the `-replace` operator instead:

```
$import -replace $remove,"$newbody"
```

### Use `-replace` in SingleLine mode

The only thing we need now, is to instruct the regex parser to treat the input in `SingleLine` mode - so that `.*?` will capture newlines as well. This is super easy though, we just add an options flag `s` at the start of the regex pattern:

```
$import -replace "(?s)$remove","$newbody"
```

And that's it :)

```
$import = Get-Content C:\bookmarks.html -Raw
$newbody = Get-Content C:\newbookmarks.html
$remove = "(?<=$([regex]::Escape('<DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1544626193" LAST_MODIFIED="1546498855">Import-IE</H3>'))).*?(?=</DL>)"
$import -replace "(?s)$remove","$newbody"
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation.
Unfortunately, I could not use Get-Content -Raw
but I had to solve it with: [string]$import = @(Get-Content -Path ($path + $bookmarkshtml)) -join [Environment]::NewLine